# Access maxlength of JSF inputfield in java custom validation

Tags: java, validation, jsf, maxlength

I need to access the `maxLength` of an `inputField` in custom validation. Although I see `maxLength` as one of the fields in `UIComponent`, I don't see a getter for the same.

Can anyone tell me how can I get the value of `maxLength` in my custom validator?

Answer (score 1):

From theory it should work if you cast the `UIComponent` to `HtmlInputText`. Then you can use `getMaxlength()` to return the value of the `maxLength` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the list of attributes defined for a `UIComponent` using `getAttributes()`. It will return a `Map<String,Object>`.

```
Map<String,Object> listAttributes = myUIComponent.getAttributes();
Integer maxLength = (Integer) listAttributes.get("maxLength");
```

[UIComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) - See getAttributes method.

[java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) - Javadoc for Map class.